# Angularjs - Dropdown multiselect

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to add an AngularJS multi select drop down by following
http://dotansimha.github.io/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect/#/

But I am not able to get it..

Here is my Plunker code

http://plnkr.co/edit/7EV9Fc?p=preview

**HTML:-**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://github.com/dotansimha/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect/blob/master/src/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect.js"> </script>
    <script src="https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/master/dist/lodash.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

<body ng-app="jayApp" ng-controller='jayController'>

Drop down : 
    <div ng-dropdown-multiselect="" options="example1data" selected-model="example1model">

    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

**Javascript**

```
var jayApp = angular.module('jayApp',[]);

jayApp.controller('jayController', function($scope) {

    $scope.example1model = []; 
    $scope.example1data = [ {id: 1, label: "David"}, {id: 2, label: "Jhon"}, {id: 3, label: "Danny"}];
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GitHub JS files you are referencing are not the actual JS files but the web page that shows the GitHub view of the JS file.  You need to include the actual JS files.

Edit: Example:

https://github.com/dotansimha/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect/blob/master/src/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect.js

vs.

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dotansimha/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect/master/src/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect.js

Answer (score 4):

Include the module in angular (i.e. in app.js) - angularjs-dropdown-multiselect

Answer (score 0):

```
var myApp = angular.module("yourAppName", [ "angularjs-dropdown-multiselect" ])
```

You need to register the module to your app.

Your path to the script was also wrong (as mentioned by another user).

I know this is 4 years too late, but hopefully this helps anyone else still using the ancient AngularJS.